# Axios Response Intercepter not passing response data, Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
(response) => {
    
    return response

}, async (error) => {

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'myrestbase',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN HERE',
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }
})

if(error.response.status == 401){
    await instance.post('/token/refresh').then(tokenResponse => {
        
        if(tokenResponse.data.status){

            error.config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + tokenResponse.data.raw_token
            
            return axios(error.config)
            // router.go(router.currentRoute)

        }else{
            
            ElMessage({
                message: 'Your session has expired! Please login again.',
                type: 'warning'
            })

            logout()

        }

    }).catch(error => {
    
        logout()

    })

} 

})
```

My interceptor seems to work as expected. If a request gets a 401 response (token expired), I refresh the token. On success, for the new token, I want to complete the original request with the updated token, which I'm attempting with axios(error.config). This works fine...but the original request response comes up `undefined`.

```
axios.get('/original_request', {
    params: payload
}).then(response => {
    
    console.log(response)

})
```

I can get by with router.go(router.currentRoute) that I have commented out, and most won't recognize a route reload in Vuejs. I would really like it to be seamless, especially if it's a POST request where the user input form fields, etc.

Anyone have any suggestions how I can get the data in the response instead of `undefined`?

Comment: If I console.log(error.config) I get

{data: undefined}

and that is what the original_request is giving back. I double checked the API, it is returning results so data should have the results.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of different testing, I realized that I needed to move what I was trying to do into the response 200 callback.

This allowed me to complete the original request

```
axios.interceptors.response.use( async (response) => {
    
    if(response.status === 202){

      await axios(response.config).then(originalResponse => {
         response.data = originalResponse.data
         response.status = originalResponse.status
         response.statusText = originalResponse.statusText
         return response
      }).catch(error => {

      })

    }

    return response

}
```

works seemlessly, and refreshing the token is silent.